# .NET Core DbContextPool vs DbContextFactory - for implementing repository

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I try to implement a repository in my infrastructure layer. I dont use dbContext as a unit of work - instead each repo method do and finish its job. I will implement transactions in a layer above to hold the repo methods together.

In my previous life (not in .NET Core) my repo methods usually were the following:

```
class MyRepo:IMyRepo
{
   public void Save(MyObject p)
   {
     using(var ctx = new MyDbContext())
     {
         ctx.MyTable.Add( ...);
         ctx.SaveChanges();
     }
```

In the fancy world of Core and DI I tried to implement the method as the following:

Way 1 - adding DbContextOptions to DI

```
class MyRepo : IMyRepo
{
    private readonly DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> Options;
    public MyRepo(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
    {
      Options = options;
    }
    public void Save(MyObject p)
    {
       using var ctx = new MyDbContext(this.Options);
       ...
```

Way 2 - adding DbContextFactory to DI

```
class MyRepo:IMyRepo
{
    private readonly DbContextFactory<MyDbContext> Factory;
    public MyRepo(DbContextFactory<MyDbContext> factory)
    {
      Factory = factory;
    }
    public void Save(MyObject p)
    {
       using var ctx = Factory.CreateDbContext();
       ...
```

Way 3 - adding DbContextPool to DI

```
class MyRepo:IMyRepo
{
    private readonly DbContextPool<MyDbContext> Pool;
    public MyRepo(DbContextPool<MyDbContext> pool)
    {
      Pool = pool;
    }
    public void Save(MyObject p)
    {
       using var ctx = Pool.GetCtxInstance(); ? ???
       ...
```

I want to unit test my repository in two ways:

- on a local .mdf file, connecting to it and perform real sql operations and check the result of them
- I plan to test domain services using a fake repository. I read that there is a way to fake a repository using "in memory tables", in this case I think I have to replace my DbContext instance during the test somehow

My questions:

- in the 3rd way how to obtain a new context instance (when pool is used?)? Or is it so simple as `ctx = new MyDbContext()`?
- is it a real life example to fake the MyDbContext itself, not only change its 'options'? How to fake it? Why?
- in this case I think the factory is the best because I can implement other ways to create dbcontext for testing later. Is it?
- so which is the best way to be able to perform unit tests on repository itself, and domain services using faked repositories?

What are your advices to implement the repository? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As for instantiating DbContext, new() always creates new object, there are no pools and no magic here. But if you registered a pool with AddDbContextPool for specific DbContext, then any such DbContext can be acquired from the pool through DI, with constructor injection or with ServiceProvider. By the way, there is also `AddPooledDbContextFactory` method if you prefer an approach with factory.

Comment: Thanks. Then a 4th way is needed, where the ServiceProvider class should be given and stored in the repo?

Answer (score 1):

> What are your advices to implement the repository?

1. Don’t.  Your  DbContext is a perfectly good repository.  Just use that.
2. If you do, inject an instance of your DbContext subtype in your extra repo.  Then DI can handle the lifetime of the DBContext and you will be able to manage transactions as you envision because all the repos in a scope will share a DbContext instance.

Comment: Its too early probably, but cannot understand you Sir. "my dbcontext" is not a repo, its a dbcontext. I understand that using DI is a way of writing code - but I dont like it. When I need an instance of anything - I must write "magic" constructors to get one. Storing and using the serviceProvider is an anti-pattern I think. I have a bad bad feeling :(

Comment: A DbContext is both a Repository and a Unit-of-Work.

Comment: Ohh, I see your point now... hm. :) thanks. :)